# React Native, ITMS-90078: Missing Push Notification Entitlement

Tags: ios, react-native, app-store

I have got this mail each time I publish my app to app store:

> Dear Developer,
>
> We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app,
> "{appName}" {version} ({build}). Your delivery was successful, but you
> may wish to correct the following issues in your next delivery:
>
> ITMS-90078: Missing Push Notification Entitlement - Your app appears
> to register with the Apple Push Notification service, but the app
> signature's entitlements do not include the 'aps-environment'
> entitlement.  If your app uses the Apple Push Notification service,
> make sure your  App ID is enabled for Push Notification in the
> Provisioning Portal,  and resubmit after signing your app with a
> Distribution provisioning  profile that includes the 'aps-environment'
> entitlement. Xcode does not  automatically copy the aps-environment
> entitlement from provisioning  profiles at build time. This behavior
> is intentional. To use this  entitlement, either enable Push
> Notifications in the project editor's  Capabilities pane, or manually
> add the entitlement to your entitlements  file. For more information,
> see https://developer.apple.com/library/
> content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/
> HandlingRemoteNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH6-SW1.
>
> After you’ve corrected the issues, you can upload a new binary to  App
> Store Connect.
>
> Best regards,
>
> The App Store Team

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add the push notification capability in signing&capability -> capability -> push notification. Make sure to add It to both the release and debug tab.

Comment: You self-answered a contradicting answer. You said you have checked the Xcode settings in your Xcode, but in your answer, you said you have to enable the capabilities in Xcode.

Comment: I haven't checked whether it is checked for all for my case it was only for Debug mistake from my end.

Answer (score 1):

For people that still have this issue or maybe another issue that happens with entitlements like `com.apple.developer.associated-domain` or `com.apple.developer.applesignin` I have a few tricks for this.

And I've already did some suggestions around the forum that I search about it like re-create the provisioning profile, keychain, certificates, etc and re-enable capability in XCode, automatic signing and manual signing provisioning profile in XCode even I did upgrade my XCode to 13 and my macOS but the issue still happens.

After I archived my code, I get this summary before I upload it to AppStore.
[image]

Actually I have another entitlements like `aps-environment`, `com.apple.developer.applesignin` and `com.apple.developer.associated-domain`. But the summary didn't include those entitlements.
Push Notif, Sign in with Apple and Universal Links work like charm in development mode, but when the I install from TestFlight those feature didn't work anymore. And I didn't get any error messages while archiving until finish upload it to AppStore just email warning about missing push notifications entitlements.

So, here's what I do:

1. Check the codesign of archive build for the app via terminal. `codesign -d --entitlements :- ${path_to_your_bundle_app}`. For me, the bundle app is in `/Users/${user}/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/${date}/${app_name}/Products/Application/${app_name}.app/${app_name}.app`.
   And what I got is
   [image]

I just realize that the bundle app didn't include any entitlements

2. And then I signing it manually from my entitlements file to the bundle app. `codesign --sign - --entitlements ${path_entitlements_file}/${filename}.entitlements --timestamp=none ${path_to_your_bundle_app}`
3. Back to XCode and go to *Window->Organizer*. And try Distribute the App again.
4. And finally the summary for all entitlements that I need is included.
   [image]

I don't know why this happen to me. Maybe there are something wrong in my config in XCode or my project code. However, now it's work in TestFlight even though I should still signing it manually after I archived my app.
Maybe anyone can help me about this. My stack is

- React Native 0.63.3
- XCode 12.5 and I update to XCode 13
- MacOS 11.6

Answer (score 0):

[![Please refer below][1]][1]

Go to Runner, signing & capabilities, click the **capabilities +** , on newer macs you'll get a popup dialogs, scroll to Push notifications and select.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqbuN.png